# Trigger an email notification if cell is changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help creating a script for Google Apps! I want to be able to send email notifications if a **specific cell** has been changed (eg: E10). Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advnace!

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far. Do you have any specific problem?

Comment: Have you gone through the Apps script documentation? Post some code what you have tried till now.  Go through this documentation:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit

Answer (score -1):

use this scipt........

```
function sheetTracker()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  if(cell=='E10')
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("email sent.....!");
    MailApp.sendEmail('me@gmail.com', 'Modification in the spreadsheet',"sheet Name:   "+ss.getName()+"\nSheet url:  "+ss.getUrl()+"\n"+ 'Cell '+cell+' has been modified by '+Session.getActiveUser()+' - new value = '+ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString());
  } 
}
```

then add below the triggers to your script....
[image]

this may solve your problem...

Comment: This doesnt detect change